# What is considered a "best practice" for the design of a set of PHP scripts which service AJAX requests?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, ajax

I am designing a website which will query a simple MySQL database using AJAX calls to PHP scripts.

I have looked into frameworks which achieve this but I'm looking for a lighter weight solution and so am rolling my own. At present I have all AJAX calls hitting a single script, which then calls further functions based on the content of POSTed variables. Those functions return objects or throw exceptions, and in my main script I either return a JSON encoded version of the object or catch the exceptions and return a JSON encoded "error object".

Does this approach sound ok or not? If not, what is best practice in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how it's supposed to work. What's your question?

Comment: Why are you looking for a lighter weight solution? Have you found out that existing implementations are too slow for you? Have you measured? If not, how will you be able to tell that your implementation is lighter than the existing ones?

Comment: I hope you are using POSTed method for right reason. So, avoided GET method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the serverside i would reommend a [restful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service#Representational_state_transfer_.28REST.29) approach.

and for the client side javascript i would recommend jQuery ($().ajax())

and it probably would't hurt to code after the principles of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller)

Comment: +1 for mentioning [REST](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife). A little more detail (or an example) would be helpful to OP, but perhaps that isn't possible, as he hasn't given any details. jQuery, though useful, isn't a "best practice". As for MVC, what do people think of ["Understanding MVC in PHP"](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html) as a guide?